# Readability or Efficiency for a ManyToMany filter

Tags: django

To check if something is a member of a manytomany I have two options:

```
if something.members.filter(username = user.username).count() > 0:
```

or

```
if user in something.members.all():
```

The second is much more readable to me, but the first seems much more efficient. Which one should be I doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would rather do:

```
something.members.filter(username=user.username).exists()
```

or even something like (faster) if your models allow that:

```
something.members.filter(user=user).exists()
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this which is more *pythonic*:

```
if something.members.filter(username = user.username):
```